# Find out less than one value among the description

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has a product description column. The customer recently reported that they found some product descriptions having less than zero values without a leading zero. For instance, "Strawberry Essence .5 Ltr" instead of "Strawberry Essence 0.5 Ltr". However, the value varies one description to another (i.e. it could be .5, .1, .4, ...etc) They wanted to find out those affected descriptions and update leading zero.

Can anyone suggest how can I write the SQL (wildcard) statement to return values that contain less than one value without leading zero in the product description?

I tried with variations of the following SQL statement;

```
select * 
from InvItems 
where description like '%.[0-9]%'
```

Comment: You should store different type of info separately. So you want 3 columns `Description, Size, Unit`

Comment: No, that is not the case. The description should show that information to the customers. Unit Of measure stores in a separate table. I have few more separate tables for other related information as well.

Comment: That is another issue: storing the same info twice. You could make up the full description with a computed column or a view `CONCAT_WS(' ', Description, Size, Unit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Space infront of the Wildcards

```
SELECT * 
FROM INVITEMS 
WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '% .[0-9]%'
```

Sample

```
SELECT NAME
FROM (
VALUES ('Strawberry Essence .5 Ltr'),('Strawberry Essence 1.5 Ltr')
)S(NAME)
WHERE NAME LIKE '% .[0-9]%'
```

Comment: @nwGCham . . . This will not work if the value is at the beginning of the string:  `'.5 ltr Coke'`.